# how to place "Orders and Returns" on navigation menu instead of a footer link

Tags: magento2, orders, menu, navigation

i would like to know if theres anyway i can place the "order and return" link and place it in the menu on the navigation bar. Here is my site. Thank you  If you notice the order and return link is at the bottom (footer)

http://23inventory.com/default/sales/guest/form/

Answer (score 0):

Place this link any where you want..

```
<a href="<?php echo rtrim($this->getUrl('sales/guest/form/', '/'));?>">Order Status</a>
```

Answer (score -1):

I open your link (http ://23inventory.com/default/sales/guest/form/), and it give me blank page.

You can adding it in header phtml : `app\design\frontend\yourtheme\default\template\page\html\header.phtml`

like this : `<div class="your-class"><a href="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl();?>ordersreturns">Orders and Returns</a></div>`

or you can use by adding it via xml

you can read it how to in here : [Adding Custom Links with local.xml](http://www.demacmedia.com/magento-commerce/magento-tutorials/adding-custom-links-local-xml/)